# How to deal with: redeclaration of C++ built-in type ‘char16_t’

Tags: c++, c, c++11, compiler-errors

In a C++11 project I have to use external C library. This library main header file defines

```
typedef uint16_t        char16_t;
```

And because of it compilation of the C++ program which includes this library fails, with the message:

```
redeclaration of C++ built-in type ‘char16_t’
```

The only idea I have is to repackage whole library but because `char16_t` is pervasive in this library it would be very time consuming (if even possible). Are there some sensible ways of dealing with this problem?

**Edit:**

I have also another idea of removing problematic line and replacing every occurrence of char16_t with uint16_t but I would have to modify third party library headers and I do not particularly like this idea (there can be more similar errors). So I also wonder whether there is some good way of dealing of broader problem of incompatibilities between C++ and C when including headers.

Comment: `C++0x11`. I hadn't heard that one yet.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17 ;)

Comment: I don't know if `#define` is sensible in your eyes...

Comment: @PlasmaHH How does `C++17` match the `C++0x11` pattern? It matches `C++1y` though. OP meant `C++0x == C++11`.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Oh my gosh... touché. That one was good. I have to use stronger coffee.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use a macro to rename the library type while keeping it unrelated to the new language type `char16_t`:

```
#define char16_t LIBRARY_char16_t
#include <library>
#undef char16_t
```

Then, the library header will be compiled in your code base such that the typedef has the name `LIBRARY_char16_t`.

The library itself is still compiled such that the type in question is typedef'ed to `uint16_t` so you should not attempt to change this (by e.g. removing the typedef) in order to stay binary-compatible with the compiled library.

Comment: Out of experience (yes, I am doing such hacks too) I would recommend to create your own header just doing this, and then always ever including that header. This way you are also prepared for more surprises.

Comment: I have never thought I will be glad for having preprocessor.

Comment: Yes @PlasmaHH that would be indeed the next step. The new headers should have the exact same name, but their directory should have higher priority in the `INCLUDE_PATH` such that you don't have to change *any* file in the code base.

Answer (score 2):

C++11 defines char32_t and char16_t as built in types. This error only happens if you are using C++11. i.e. in your **Application.mk** file you have:

```
APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

You can either remove the C++11 support, **OR** use the following workaround, that should probably be a part of the official Android source (if not already).

in file **/frameworks/native/include/utils/Unicode.h**

```
#if __cplusplus <= 199711L
typedef uint32_t char32_t;
typedef uint16_t char16_t;
#endif
```

It is based on answers from [a question about char16/32_t with C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29945236/using-char16-t-char32-t-etc-without-c-11)