# Using char16_t, char32_t etc without C++ 11?

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to have fixed width types including character types. `<stdint.h>` provides types for integers, but not characters, unless when using C++11, which i can't do.

Is there a clean way to define these types (`char16_t`, `char32_t`, etc) without conflicting with those defined by C++11 in case the source would ever be mixed with C++11 ?

Thank you :)

Comment: `char16_t` and `char32_t` are fundamental types that were added to the language. You cannot provide such types yourself. That last requirement rules out any sort of `typedef`s too.

Comment: is there a reason why you don't want to use uint32_t and int32_t?

Comment: Because i want to use *int* for integral values and *char* for characters, even if they are almost the same thing in the end. It looks more intuitive to use *char* than *int* when manipulating characters and strings.

@Praetorian What prevents me from doing typedef uint16_t uchar16_t ? I just want to know a way to do that without creating conflicts, if possible.

Comment: I would also vote for `typedef uint16_t char16_t` if C++11 is not used.

Comment: Well yes, you can call it something other than `char16_t` to avoid future conflicts if the code is compiled under C++11. Your solution still doesn't make it a distinct type, but maybe you can live with that.

Comment: Aren't there some defines in the C++11 headers that can be used to disable the definition of these types by the standard headers for cases where they are already user-defined ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checking whether this types are supported is a platform-dependent thing, I think. For example, GCC defines: `__CHAR16_TYPE__` and `__CHAR32_TYPE__` if these types are provided (requires either ISO C11 or C++ 11 support).

However, you cannot check for their presence directly, because they are fundamental types, not macros:

> In C++, char16_t and char32_t are fundamental types (and thus this header does not define such macros in C++).

However, you could check for C++ 11 support. According to [Bjarne Stroustrup's](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#11) page:

> **__cplusplus**
>
> In C++11 the macro `__cplusplus` will be set to a value that differs from (is greater than) the current 199711L.

So, basically, you could do:

```
#if __cplusplus > 199711L
// Has C++ 11, so we can assume presence of `char16_t` and `char32_t`
#else
// No C++ 11 support, define our own
#endif
```

How define your own?

**->** MSVC, ICC on Windows: use [platform-specific types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29dh1w7z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), supported in VS .NET 2003 and newer:

```
typedef __int16 int16_t;
typedef unsigned __int16 uint16_t;
typedef __int32 int32_t;
typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t;
```

**->** GCC, MinGW, ICC on Linux: these have full C99 support, so use types from `<cstdint>` and don't `typedef` your own (you may want to check version or compiler-specific macro).

And then:

```
typedef int16_t char16_t;
typedef uint16_t uchar16_t;
typedef int32_t char32_t;
typedef uint32_t uchar32_t;
```

How to check what compiler is in use? Use [this great page](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/) (['Compilers' section](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/)).

Comment: I presume, you should use `int_least16_t` and `int_least32_t` from <stdint.h> where possible.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but what can i do if `sizeof( short )` is neither 2 or 4 using VS2005 ? :X EDIT: The compiler does not like : `#if sizeof(short) == 2`

Comment: Yes, `sizeof()` should not work inside `#if`. This part of my solution was a pseudo-code. See updated answer. You can either use my approach and typedef integral types depending on platform, or look at the [ctsdint.hpp from Boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/boost/cstdint.hpp), which shows few useful things, that should be done to portably define explicitly sized integral types.

Comment: `char16_t` and `char32_t` are unsigned (specifically "It has the same size, signedness, and alignment as `std::uint_least16_t`/`uint_least32_t`").